# conjugate subgroups of the symmetric group

Tags: group-theory

Let $S_n$ be the symmetric group. let $H=S_{d_1}\times\cdots \times S_{d_k}$ such that $d_1+\cdots + d_k=n$.

What does the following statement means:

> every two embeddings of $H$ in $S_n$ are conjugate.

In my opinion this means that changing the order of $d_i$ gives conjugate subgroups. For example $S_{d_1}\times S_{d_2}\times S_{d_3}$ is conjugate to 
 $S_{d_2}\times S_{d_1}\times S_{d_3}$ and to $S_{d_3}\times S_{d_1}\times S_{d_2}$ and so on ...

Comment: In general, when faced with a term you don't know, it's best to ask the source (whether text or person) for a definition rather than assuming a meaning arbitrarily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your interpretation is correct. It is certainly *not true* that any subgroups of $S_n$ that are abstractly isomorphic to $H$ are conjugate. The most famous example is that of two non-conjugate $S_5$ sitting inside $S_6$. So the statement must refer to the canonical embedding of $H$ in $S_n$, in which case the only way I can think of to obtain different embeddings is by permuting the $d_i$ (and then the statement is almost trivially true).

Comment: I think it's more likely that the interpretation is incorrect, that the standard meaning of embedding is intended, and that the quoted statement is false (perhaps as part of a true/false question).  This is entirely conjectural since neither of us has the initial source, unlike palio.

Comment: @Alex B. : thanks!! please where can i read on the example of two non conjugate $s_5$ sitting in $S_6$?

Comment: @user92843 : $S_{d_i}$ is embedded in $S_n$ as the subgroup permuting the $d_i$ first elements of $(x_1,...,x_{d_i},x_{d_{i+1}},...,x_n)$

Comment: @palio See e.g. JA Todd, The Odd Number 6, Math. Proc. Camb. Phil. Soc. 41 (1945) or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automorphisms_of_the_symmetric_and_alternating_groups#Exotic_map_S5_.E2.86.92_S6